# How Do I Remove a CSS Value

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working with zurb foundation 5, and I want to have a fullsize cover on the front.

But because zurb sets the position of the body "relative", I have trouble setting absolute positioned Divs.

Here is the jsfiddle and when you just remove the:

```
 body {
      position: relative;
 }
```

you will see, how I actually want it to look like.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZULv9/

I guess I could remove it from the framework, but I rather would like to overwrite it or just to remove the css value in hindsight to keep the my hands out of the framework. I believe that it must be possible somehow, I just haven't found out how this is done.

Therefore I would be happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the body styling to:

```
position: static;
```

which display all elements in order of how they appear in document flow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
      position: absolute !important;
 }
```

css override